# How to group a list of maps by key Scala 2.11.x

Tags: scala, group-by, functional-programming, maps

Given the following list of maps (list could be longer):

```scala
List(
    Map[String,String]("wind"->"none", "rain"->"none", "class"->"on time"),
    Map[String,String]("wind"->"none", "rain"->"slight", "class"->"on time"),
    Map[String,String]("wind"->"none", "rain"->"slight", "class"->"late"),
    ...
)
```

How can I group the maps that I have something like this:

```scala
"on time" -> ("wind"->"none", "rain"->"none", "wind"->"none", "rain"->"slight")
"late" -> ("wind"->"none", "rain"->"slight")
```

I get stuck at working on several maps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
val maps =
  List(
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "none", "class" -> "on time"),
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight", "class" -> "on time"),
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight", "class" -> "late"),
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight")
  )

val grouped = maps.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[(String, String)]]) {
  case (acc, map) if map.contains("class") =>
    val key = map("class")
    if (acc.contains(key))
      acc.updated(key, acc(key) ++ (map - "class").toList)
    else 
      acc + (key -> (map - "class").toList)
  case (acc, _) => acc
}
```

Comment: You may use `get` in the `Map` to avoid the `contains` check. Something like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/n6GXpKNhSZS3uFaH8ELvbQ/3

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, yes. Would have removed conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla Scala `2.12\2.11` assuming the starting point:

```scala
val maps =
  List(
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "none", "class" -> "on time"),
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight", "class" -> "on time"),
    Map[String, String]("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight", "class" -> "late")
  )
```

you could fold everything:

```scala
maps
  .filter(_.contains("class")) // guarantee "class" key exists
  .map(m => m("class") -> (m - "class").toList)
  .foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[(String, String)]]) { 
    case (acc, (key, values)) if acc.contains(key) => 
      acc.updated(key, acc(key) ++ values)
    case (acc, (key, values)) => 
      acc + ((key, values))
  }
```

This logic is safe with any input as it will filter out `Map[_,_]` without `class` key.
You could remove that `.map(..)` and do everything in one go in the `fold`.

If you can guarantee the input is non-empty and contains key `class` you  could use `reduceLeft` instead of `foldLeft` and drop the `filter`.

**Bonus** the logic is compatible with `Iterator[_]`:

```scala
maps
  .iterator
  .filter(..)
  .map(..)
  .foldLeft(..)(..)
}
```