# Count occurence of key values from several maps grouped by a key in scala 2.11.x

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Imagine the following list of maps (which could be potentially longer):

```scala
List(
Map[String,String]("wind"->"high", "rain"->"heavy", "class"->"very late"),
Map[String,String]("wind"->"none", "rain"->"slight", "class"->"on time"),
Map[String,String]("wind"->"high", "rain"->"none", "class"->"very late"),
...
)
```

How can I get to the following form:

```scala
Map("very late" -> Set(("wind",Map("high" -> 2)), ("rain",Map("heavy" -> 1, "none" -> 1))),
"on time" -> Set(("wind",Map("none" -> 1)), ("rain",Map("slight" -> 1))))
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? Also, specify your **Scala** version

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I tried the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401812/how-to-group-a-list-of-maps-by-key-scala-2-11-x/70401996?noredirect=1#comment124457503_70401996 but I got stuck at the point of mapping the set. Scala version is 2.11.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you what you want.

```
val maps = List(...)

maps.groupBy(_.getOrElse("class","no-class"))
  .mapValues(_.flatMap(_ - "class").groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues(_.map(_._2).groupBy(identity)
      .mapValues(_.length)
    ).toSet
  )
```

The problem is, what you want isn't a good place to be.

The result type is `Map[String,Set[(String,Map[String,Int])]]` which is a terrible hodgepodge of collection types. Why `Set`? What purpose does that serve? How is this useful? How do you retrieve meaningful data from it?

This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Thanks so much. The term XY problem is now a new concept in my thinking repertoire.  It also seems to me that the division in so many collection types makes no sense but I didn't chose the way of how it should be implemented...

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions.

First using `Set`, which looks like what you want,

```
val grouped2 = maps.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Set[(String, Map[String, Int])]]) {
  case (acc, map) =>
    map.get("class").fold(acc) { key =>
      val keyOpt = acc.get(key)
      if (keyOpt.isDefined) {
        val updatedSet = (map - "class").foldLeft(Set.empty[(String, Map[String, Int])]) {
          case (setAcc, (k1, v1)) =>
            keyOpt.flatMap(_.find(_._1 == k1)).map { tup =>
              setAcc + ((k1, tup._2.get(v1).fold(tup._2 ++ Map(v1 -> 1))(v => tup._2 + ((v1, v + 1)))))
            }.getOrElse(setAcc + (k1 -> Map(v1 -> 1)))
        }
        acc.updated(key, updatedSet)
      } else {
        acc + (key -> (map - "class").map(tup => (tup._1, Map(tup._2 -> 1))).toSet)
      }
    }
}
```

and then using a `Map`,

```
val grouped1 = maps.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]) {
  case (acc, map) =>
    map.get("class").fold(acc) { key =>
      val keyOpt = acc.get(key)
      if (keyOpt.isDefined) {
        val updatedMap = (map - "class").foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Map[String, Int]]) {
          case (mapAcc, (k1, v1)) =>
            keyOpt.flatMap(_.get(k1)).map{ statMap =>
              mapAcc + ((k1, statMap.get(v1).fold(statMap ++ Map(v1 -> 1))(v => statMap + ((v1, v + 1)))))
            }.getOrElse(mapAcc + (k1 -> Map(v1 -> 1)))
        }
        acc.updated(key, updatedMap)
      } else {
        acc + (key -> (map - "class").map(tup => (tup._1, Map(tup._2 -> 1))))
      }
    }
}
```

I was [playing with](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ShbkDMIPQbaYxfZzNWsnzg) `Map` version and changed it to `Set`. In a few days, I don't think I will understand everything above just by looking at it. So, I have tried to make it as understandable as possible for me. Adapt this to your own solution or wait for others.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes another implementation, which uses the `keySet` method of `Map` to join two maps together.
Also, note that I changed the output type from a `Map` to a `Set` of tuples whose second value is another `Map`. To three nested `Maps` which, IMHO, makes more sense.

```scala
def groupMaps[K, V](groupingKey: K, data: List[Map[K, V]]): Map[V, Map[K, Map[V, Int]]] =
  data.foldLeft(Map.empty[V, Map[K, Map[V, Int]]]) {
    case (acc, map) =>
      map.get(key = groupingKey).fold(ifEmpty = acc) { groupingValue  =>
        val newValues = (map - groupingKey).map {
          case (key, value) =>
            key -> Map(value -> 1)
        }
        
        val finalValues = acc.get(key = groupingValue).fold(ifEmpty = newValues) { oldValues =>
          (oldValues.keySet | newValues.keySet).iterator.map { key =>
            val oldMap = oldValues.getOrElse(key = key, default = Map.empty[V, Int])
            val newMap = newValues.getOrElse(key = key, default = Map.empty[V, Int])
            
            val finalMap = (oldMap.keySet | newMap.keySet).iterator.map { value =>
              val oldCount = oldMap.getOrElse(key = value, default = 0)
              val newCount = newMap.getOrElse(key = value, default = 0)
              
              value -> (oldCount + newCount)
            }.toMap
            
            key -> finalMap
          }.toMap
        }
        
        acc.updated(key = groupingValue, finalValues)
      }
  }
```

Which can be used like this:

```scala
val maps =
  List(
    Map("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "none", "class" -> "on time"),
    Map("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight", "class" -> "on time"),
    Map("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight", "class" -> "late"),
    Map("wind" -> "none", "rain" -> "slight")
  )
val result = groupMaps(groupingKey = "class", maps)
// val result: Map[Strig, Map[String, Map[String, Int]]] =
//  Map(
//    on time -> Map(wind -> Map(none -> 2), rain -> Map(none -> 1, slight -> 1)),
//    late -> Map(wind -> Map(none -> 1), rain -> Map(slight -> 1))
//  )
```

If you need to maintain the output type you asked for, then you can just do a `.mapValue(_.toSet)` at the end of the `foldLeft`

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/n6GXpKNhSZS3uFaH8ELvbQ/5)*

Comment: PS: Note that using **Scala** `2.13` and **cats** the code can be significantly shorter: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/n6GXpKNhSZS3uFaH8ELvbQ/11